# RangeError while uploading large files using streams in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-upload, http-post

I am coding a program in Node.js for uploading files to a server. In the request handler method, I am using fs.createWriteStream(). It works fine for all files with a size of less than 2 GB. But I am getting RangeError for files with size of 2 GB or more. Here is the stack trace:

```
RangeError: Invalid typed array length
at Buffer.Uint8Array (native)
at FastBuffer (buffer.js:8:1)
at createUnsafeBuffer (buffer.js:33:12)
at allocate (buffer.js:176:12)
at Function.Buffer.allocUnsafe (buffer.js:136:10)
at Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:327:23)
at internals.Recorder.collect
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Show all the relevant code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.route({
method: 'POST',
path: '/upload',
config: {
    payload: {
        output: 'stream',
        parse: true,
        allow: 'multipart/form-data',
        maxBytes: 2147483648,
        timeout: false
    },
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        console.log('Uploading to local server...');
        var data = request.payload;
        if (!data.asset)
            reply({ success: false, errType : 0, msg: 'File not sent' }).type('application/json');

        var assetName = data.asset.hapi.filename;
        fs.stat(`${__dirname}/uploads`, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                fs.mkdirSync(`${__dirname}/uploads`);
            }

            var path = __dirname + "/uploads/" + assetName;
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
            file.on('error', function (err) {
                console.error(new Error(err));
                reply({ success: false, errType : 1, msg: err, filename: assetName }).type('application/json');
            });
            data.asset.pipe(file);
            data.asset.on('end', function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(new Error(err));
                    reply({ success: false, errType : 1, msg: err, filename: assetName }).type('application/json');
                }
```

This is a part of the code. The payload is converted to stream and then it is written into a file.